# Flask SqlAlchemy map json to model class

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I am fairly new to python. My problem is I have a SqlAlchemy model class say Message which has 150 properties like so:

```
class Message(database.Model):
    id = database.Column(database.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = database.Column(database.String(80), unique=True)
    email = database.Column(database.String(120), unique=True)

    def getId(self):
        return self.id;

    def getUserName(self):
        return self.username;

    def getEmail(self):
        return self.email;
class DataTesting(object):
    def datatest(self):
        kwargs = json.loads(self.getData())
        instance = Message(**kwargs)
        print(instance.getUserName())


    def getData(self):
        return """
        {
         "id": 1,
         "username": "user1",
         "email": "email1"
        }
        """
```

I am calling datatest() from another class.

I received the JSON from the source which has all the keys which are defined in Message class. My requirement is to map JSON to Message class object and then save this object in db. I don't want to wite from_json() because the number of properties are too high and don't want to use constructor because of the same reason. I need something which can transform my json to Message class. Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: do you need something like `import json` `kwargs= json.loads(JSON_str)` `instance=Message(**kwargs)`?

Comment: Got error TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
Edited my question

Comment: can't you just iterate over all the keys in json?

Comment: Iterating not going to solve the problem as I might have to put check for all keys eg if key ==''someKey" then assign it to "someProperty"

Comment: when i run the above code, and call `DataTesting().datatest()`, it gives the expected output.

Comment: Thanks @e.s. your solution is working. And I also messed something with imports thats why I was getting TypeError: 'module' object is not callable